# Text hidden behind div

Tags: html, css

I have a cloud made with HTML/CSS and I'm trying to include some text in the center of it. But I'm having trouble positioning it and having it overlap over the cloud divs.

```css
#cloud {
    height: 230px;
    margin: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}

#cloud div {
    border: solid 5px black;
}

#bottom_c {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100px;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 0;
}

#right_c{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    left: 140px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 40px; 
    width: 150px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#left_c{
    background-color: #fff;  
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 70px; 
    width: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#cloud::before {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    left: 55px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 75px; 
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cloud::after {
    position: absolute; top: 45px; left: 145px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div id="cloud">
  <div id="bottom_c"></div>
  <div id="right_c">
    <p class="text">
      this is some text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="left_c">

  </div>
</div>
```

Not entirely sure how to make it work, I thought the z-index would allow the text to take "priority" and show first, but it doesn't seem to be working. Do I need to insert the p tags inside another div? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Nesting plays a big role when it comes to `z-indexes`. "If an element `B` sits on top of element `A`, a child element of element `A` can never be higher than element `B`." As such, I think you'll need to change your HTML structure to achieve your desired layout. I'd recommend separating out the text entirely :)

Comment: I think Obsidian Age has your answer, but hey! thanks for making a runnable snippet. Good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the text element from its current nesting level. Just make it a sibling of the border divs. Still one overall container.

```css
#cloud {
    height: 230px;
    margin: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}

#cloud div {
    border: solid 5px black;
}

#bottom_c {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100px;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 0;
}

#right_c{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    left: 140px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 40px; 
    width: 150px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#left_c{
    background-color: #fff;  
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 70px; 
    width: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#cloud::before {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    left: 55px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 75px; 
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cloud::after {
    position: absolute; top: 45px; left: 145px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 135px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="cloud">
  <div id="bottom_c"></div>
  <div id="right_c"></div>
  <div id="left_c"></div>
  <p class="text">this is some text</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Had to change the top margin for the text but it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you change your html to:

```
<div id="cloud">
  <div id="bottom_c"></div>
  <div id="right_c"></div>
  <div id="left_c"></div>
</div>
<p class="text">
  this is some text
</p>
```

and the text element in css to:

```
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top:200px;
  right:200px;
}
```

then it works.